# Please explain what (.:format) means

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In ruby on rails when I run 'rake routes' the output for example is

```
                Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                           Controller#Action
                 users GET    /users(.:format)                      users#index
                       POST   /users(.:format)                      users#create
```

what does the (.:format) mean?

Comment: .json, .xml, mostly. The format of the request, what success the responds_to.

Comment: Thank you Dave for taking the time to answer, but I have to tell you that your answer wasn't detailed enough it wasn't until I read 'ream88' answer below that I understood what you meant.

Comment: That's why it was a comment, and not an full answer, despite it actually answering what the `.:format` means.

Comment: Ah, makes sense now.  Thanks Dave!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Parentheses inside a route define an optional route segment.
- A colon followed by a name (in this case `:format`) defines a variable, which can be accessed later in your controller via the `params` hash.

Depending on your controller, your users can be retrieved in multiple formats in this particular example (e.g. `/users.json` and `/users.xml`). When the format variable is omitted (e.g. accessing `/users`),  Rails defaults to the HTML format.

Be sure to check the offical [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) and especially the sections [**3.1 Bound Parameters**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#bound-parameters) and [**3.2 Dynamic Segments**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments) for more information.

Comment: Excellent information, thank you for the detail.
I haven't had a chance to read through the links yet, but I will read them, so maybe they answer my next question... how do you know what the available formats are?  Such as how did everyone know that .json and .xml were available formats?

Comment: Look into your controller, current Rails versions offer `.json` and `.html` by default. Again, the Rails Guides have a [section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rendering-xml-and-json-data) about this. And be sure to check [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/224-controllers-in-rails-3) too.

Comment: Thanks again! One last question since you seem really good at Rails. I'm obviously just learning here and doing it by reading a book and then trying to build a site.  How did you learn rails? Did you jump right in or did you read the rails guides first? Could you kind of give a quick summary of how you learned? Then I promise I'll leave you alone :)

Comment: I learned in Ruby with a german ebook and then jumped right in into my first Rails app. This was around 2007, when the awesome RailsCasts just had started. They helped me a lot, maybe they can help you too even if some of them are already dated. Just start by #1 and proceed, the syntax may have changed since then, but the spirit of Rails is still the same :)

Answer (score 1):

The format refers the the data format being requested. This might be JSON or XML, so your route would match:

```
/users.json or /users.xml
```

Leaving this blank, gives the HTML version.